# Dictionary/For loops only returns one value?

Tags: python

I create `list_cv` and wanted to write a function which returns the name of people, so for example if I type `has_expereince_as(list_cv,'bi_analyst')` it should return the value 'Marry' and 'James'.
However, my function only returns one value 'Marry' when I give 'bi analyst'.
I couldn't find the reason why.

```
list_cv =[{'user': 'Marry','jobs': ['data analyst','bi analyst']},
           {'user': 'John','jobs': ['data specialist', 'data engineer', 'financial analyst']},
           {'user': 'James','jobs': ['bi analyst', 'cloud engineer', 'data analyst']}]

 def has_experience_as(list_cv,job_title):
     position=[]
     for i in range(len(list_cv)):
         if job_title in (list_cv[i]['jobs']):
             position.append(list_cv[i]['user'])
             return position

             has_experience_as(list_cv,'data analyst')
```

It only returns 'Marry'

Comment: Move the `return position` statement 8 spaces to the left.

Comment: it should also return 'James' as it has also value 'data analyst',,!

Answer (score 2):

This line must be *outside* the for loop:

```
return position
```

Currently, you're returning after appending the first position, you want to wait until all positions are appended before returning the result.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have your return inside the loop. Use this code, and you should be good:

```
list_cv =[{'user': 'Marry','jobs': ['data analyst','bi analyst']},
           {'user': 'John','jobs': ['data specialist', 'data engineer', 'financial analyst']},
           {'user': 'James','jobs': ['bi analyst', 'cloud engineer', 'data analyst']}]

def has_experience_as(list_cv,job_title):
    position=[]
    for i in range(len(list_cv)):
        if job_title in (list_cv[i]['jobs']):
            position.append(list_cv[i]['user'])

    return position

has_experience_as(list_cv,'data analyst')
```

Comment: @VivianKim Sure! Feel free to accept my answer then

Answer (score 0):

Were you meaning to return on the first pass or did you want to iterate through before returning?

```
list_cv =[{'user': 'Marry','jobs': ['data analyst','bi analyst']},
          {'user': 'John','jobs': ['data specialist', 'data engineer', 'financial analyst']},
          {'user': 'James','jobs': ['bi analyst', 'cloud engineer', 'data analyst']}]

def has_experience_as(list_cv,job_title):
    position=[]
    for i in range(len(list_cv)):
        if job_title in (list_cv[i]['jobs']):
            position.append(list_cv[i]['user'])
    return position

has_experience_as(list_cv,'data analyst')
```

Comment: Python works on indentation to close code blocks (loops, methods, classes, if statements) by bringing the return statement inline line with the def code block it will not return until fully iterated through the list.

Comment: It looks like in the time I was typing up my response the others posted theirs.